# Jquery reloading the entire page instead of just form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a quiz app. I need to create a panel to add questions. Now this is the AJAX code am using. I am having two issues with the following piece of code. 
(i) The page reloads entirely after the ajax function is called.
(ii) Strangely enough, sometimes the data gets submitted and sometimes not.

I am not sure as to where I am making the mistake. Kindly help. Thanks :)

```
    function ajaxinsert() {
    var questionVal = $("#question").val();
    var option1 = $("#optiona").val();
    var option2 = $("#optionb").val();
    var option3 = $("#optionc").val();
    var option4 = $("#optiond").val();
    //alert(questionVal+option1+option2+option3);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'admin/insertQuestion',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            question: questionVal,
            optiona: option1,
            optionb: option2,
            optionc: option3,
            optiond: option4
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (reply) {
            console.log(reply);
        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("Desc :: " + desc + "\nError :: " + err);
        }
    });
}
$("#insert-button").on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ajaxinsert();
});
```

Comment: can u please share admin/insertQuestion code?

Comment: Sure. Here it is. http://pastebin.com/P80UyCxg

Comment: Check your console for errors, if necessary tell it to persist across page reloads so you can see what happened before the page reloads. Also (unrelated to your problem) you can use `console.log('Desc', desc, 'Error', error)` instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: Ok Please change the event 'submit' to 'click' for insert-button

Comment: @meagar no, not when the event is bound to the button. It's either `$(buttonEl).on('click')` or `$(formEl).on('submit')`.

Comment: @Joeytje50 Yes, I didn't realize the code in question was being bound to a button instead of the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be binding to the `submit` event on your *form itself*, not on the submit button.

Comment: Thanks. That works perfectly. Actually I saw a advice asking to bind to submit, and since the button had the type submit, I misunderstood.